# Check if a JSON is empty using Circe

Tags: json, scala, circe

Does `circe` provide any function to check if an `io.circe.Json` object is empty?

The [Json](https://circe.github.io/circe/api/io/circe/Json.html) documentation doesn't report anything about it, while the [JsonObject](https://circe.github.io/circe/api/io/circe/JsonObject.html) documentation talks about an [isEmpty](https://circe.github.io/circe/api/io/circe/JsonObject.html#isEmpty:Boolean) function, but I verified that

```
 {}.asJson.asObject.isEmpty // false
```

so it doesn't work as I expected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It does not work in a way you expected, because [`Json.asObject`](https://circe.github.io/circe/api/io/circe/Json.html#asObject:Option%5Bio.circe.JsonObject%5D) returns `Some` in case if underlying JSON is object, because apart of that it also can either `String`, `Number`, `Null` or `Array`, hence `"{}".asObject` (not really correct just for sake of example) - returns `Some(JsonObject())` and you receive `false` because `Some.isEmpty=false`.
What you want is :

```
import io.circe._, io.circe.parser._
val emptyJsonObject = parse("{}").toOption.get //Unsafe operation for sake of answer example - DO NOT do it in production code.
println(emptyJsonObject.asObject) // prints `Some(object[])`
println(emptyJsonObject.asObject.exists(_.nonEmpty)) //prints `false`
```

Scastie: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/GgHGChNoRlGq0HxmSkf76Q

Answer (score 0):

I just forgot that as `asObject` returns an `Option[JsonObject]`, so the `isEmpty` is just checking that it's `Some`

```
.asObject.map(_.isEmpty).getOrElse(true)
```

works

Comment: Why would `.getOrElse(true)` make sense here? Do you really want a `true` if your json is not an object?

Comment: Like what would be a name for such a function, `isJsonEmptyObjectOrNotAnObject` or `isJsonNotANonEmptyObject`? Just making sure this is what you need,

Comment: Yeah maybe I had to highlight better the fact that I'm sure that the _thing_ I'm handling is actually an object, so I'm sure that `asObject` will return a `Some`